# XSLT creation from XML and load into CSV file

Tags: xml, xslt, sas

i need to convert XML files into CSV .

**Expected Output :**

```
tag1  tag2   Typearray
Name1 Name2     1
Name1 Name2     13
```

using XSLT am able to get only one record the second record in the array is getting rejected.

```
tag1,tag2,CommOffer,TypeArray
name1,name2,1
```

Can you please let me know how to read the array value using XSLT ?

Sample XML :

```
    <Master2>
       <Child1>
          <tag1>name1</tag1>
          <tag2>name2</tag2>
          <TypeArray>
             <value>1</value>
             <value>13</value>
          </TypeArray>     
      </Child1>
    </Master2>
</Master1>
```

XSLT :

```
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <xsl:text>tag1,tag2,TypeArray</xsl:text> 
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> 
         <xsl:for-each select="Master1/Master2/Child1">
             <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize- 
              space(tag1)"/></xsl:call-template>
             <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
             <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize- 
              space(tag2)"/></xsl:call-template>
             <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="TypeArray/value"/> 
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You tagged this [tag:sas] - are you using SAS to write this out?

Comment: yes am using PROC XSL in sas 9.4M2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to deduce the required logic from a single example. If - as it seems - you want to create a row for each `TypeArray/value`, with the `tag1` and `tag2` values repeated in each row, you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/Master1">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>tag1,tag2,TypeArray&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Master2/Child1">
        <xsl:variable name="tags">
            <xsl:value-of select="tag1"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tag2"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="TypeArray/value">
            <xsl:value-of select="$tags"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```